# Python Selenium - Instances of Edge still open after calling the quit() method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

### Hi,

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from time import sleep

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True

with Edge(options=edge_options) as wd:
    wd.get('https://www.google.com')
    sleep(5)
    wd.quit()
```

I'm using the Edge browser (Version 85.0.564.51) included in Windows 10 and the matching edgedriver.

Whenever I run this code, it runs without errors, but after it terminates, an msedge.exe-Process is left running.
Sometimes an entry is also added to the Run-Folder of the registry with the following content:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --type=service --enable-logging --log-level=0 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10028_1475876327" /prefetch:8
```

This points to a folder in the temp directory which I believe should be deleted when the process finishes, but since the process does not finish it is still there.

This *scoped_dir*-folder contains the following file:

```
[3532:6176:0915/120323.266:WARNING:account_consistency_mode_manager.cc(196)] Desktop Identity Consistency cannot be enabled as no OAuth client ID and client secret have been configured.
[3700:268:0915/120325.975:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(107,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(102,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:8084:0915/120326.115:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(121,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(116,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:15952:0915/120326.481:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(225,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(220,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:18152:0915/120326.585:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(155,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(150,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(91,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:18404:0915/120326.630:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(131,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(126,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:11452:0915/120326.648:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(158,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(153,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

[3700:21892:0915/120326.667:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257): 
C:\fakepath(174,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(169,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
```

I also tried adding the 'silent' option, but that did not change the outcome.
What do I have to do to close everything that is spawned by this simple script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below. I use the code below and the instances of msedge.exe will be killed after calling `quit()`. Please note to change the path in the code to your owns:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from time import sleep

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(executable_path = r"your_path_to_webdriver\msedgedriver.exe", options = edge_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Result:

[image]